# Can I use Google Drive inside Redmine?

Tags: richtextbox, redmine, google-drive-api

I would like to have a richtext solution like Google Drive inside Redmine so that I can keep requirements, use cases and etc inside of it.

I would like to link it to Google Drive since I want to have some file templates (for instance, a MS Word template in the GDrive format) for the users to fill.

The regular richtext plugins don't satisfy my needs because they are not "as cool" and popular as GDrive's.

Answer (score 2):

Google is your friend. It's a price-based model, but it looks like it'll be what you want: https://zapier.com/zapbook/google-drive/redmine/

Comment: I'm afraid that would not do for me. I need some cost free solution. Thanks for your answer anyway!